# Windows 10 Update gives error code 0x800f0922 after System Reserved Partition deleted

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-10-upgrade

There are two disk in my computer, Disk 0 and Disk 1.
Disk 0 is unused for a long time.

One day I move the whole Windows 10 using a certain software from Disk 1 to Disk 0 (due to the lack of space).
Although the System Reserved Partition and the Windows Recovery Partition were deleted (intentionally but with no special reason), the computer is able to boot perfectly since the software handled the boot files for me.

But from that day every time Windows try to update itself, it fails and gives the error code `0x800f0922`.
Is this really due to the missing System Reserved Partition?

I did try to create a new one, but creating boot files by `bcdboot` has no effect at all, and it failed on running `bootrec`.
(I also run `chkdsk` and it said that there are no problem at all.)

Is there any way to create a new System Reserved Partition without reinstalling Windows *or* can I fix `0x800f0922` without System Reserved Partition? (Windows 10 Home Edition 64-bit version 2004)

Answer (score 0):

It is quite unclear how you did what you did.

Nonetheless a normal Windows 10 install has 3 partitions:  UEFI (this is what you call system reserved), main Windows, and Windows recovery.

You need the first one for sure. I think you can run and update without the recovery.

UEFI is built by Windows when Windows is installed - not just moved into place.

So truly at this point, the best medium to long term solution is to back up your information and reinstall Windows properly on the disk you wish to use.

Comment: Is there any chance to keep all software and registry keys untouched, just like the startup repair mentioned below, if the Windows really have to be reinstalled?

Comment: Removing important partitions causes a large issue. I am fairly sure a Repair Install will not work properly. If there was less issue, I would say try it, but here you are almost for sure better off to reinstall Windows.

Comment: Also, Windows 10 needs to be running (even it it has problems) to to a Repair Install. I should have mentioned that.

Answer (score 0):

Error 0x800f0922 occurs when you have less than 500 MB in the
System Reserved partition. In your case, the partition doesn't exist at all.

I suggest deleting whatever partition you have created,
leave unallocated space on your disk of about 1 GB,
then do the following two actions.
The first one may be enough.

1. [Run Startup Repair](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/27649-run-startup-repair-windows-10-a.html)
2. [Repair Install](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html).

Comment: Unfortunately I am unable to run startup repair – the Windows Recovery Partition is also deleted – that's why I ask the question.

Comment: Make sure you have enough unallocated space on your disk, and the installation will do the allocating for you.